# Ionic2 Dev environment URL Rewrite

Tags: angular, ionic3

When using hashless routing in Ionic2, and actualizing a route, or even going to a specific route in the address bar, the routing fail

> Cannot get /home

This issue is caused by the absence of a url rewrite we'd have in production mode.
I only have a ionic.config.json file, so I'm not even sure if it's using webpack.

Is there a way to configure url rewriting (to index.html) in `ionic serve` ?

Ionic: 3.6.0 / Angular: 4.1.3

Comment: That seems to be an issue in the routing of your web server, check if there's a request to /home in your web server.

Comment: This is in development mode, local as in `ionic serve`